# Variable usage for a data reference in terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm using the below lines in a module say ABC:

```
additional_users = [
    {
      name     = each.value.mysql_db_user
      password = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.each.value.mysql_db_secret.secret_data
    }
  ]
```

Using a data source to fetch password from secret manager module:

```
data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "mysql_db_password_001" {
  project  = var.project_id
  provider = google-beta
  secret   = var.mysql_secret_id_001
  depends_on = [
    module.mysql_db_password_001
  ]
}
```

Using for-each to loop around multiple variables in the module ABC, but when i am using in below line I run into errors.

```
password = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.each.value.mysql_db_secret.secret_data
```

I guess only static values can be passed while referencing here, is there some workaround to it where I can grab values for `password` from various datasources `mysql_db_password_001` `mysql_db_password_002` `mysql_db_password_003` and so on.

Thank You !

Comment: Can you share the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like?
Index can also be `*`

```
password = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version. mysql_db_password_001[index]
```

sorry, had to answer instead of comment... to few reputation